# Replace multiple link with button

Tags: jquery, replace, hyperlink

I have a code that works to replace the url of a link with a given id

I want this code to work for multiple links and player with the same specified id or class

I have one button that should change all together

Can you guide me or help me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#change').on('click', function(e) {
 var purl = $("#urlchange").attr("href");
purl = purl .replace("dl.faz2music.ir", "up.faz2music.ir");
 $("#urlchange").attr("href",purl);
notice.showToast({text: 'Links converted',type: 'success',showClose: true});
});
});
```

```
<button id="change" class="ltr">change link's</button>

<a href="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [320].mp3"  id="urlchange">Download</a>
<a href="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [128].mp3"  id="urlchange">Download</a>

<audio><source type="audio/mp3" src="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [320].mp3" id="urlchange"></audio>
<audio><source type="audio/mp3" src="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [128].mp3" id="urlchange"></audio>
```

This code replaces only one link

I want to be able to do the same for several links with the same ID or Class

Jquery

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id. ID must always be unique. Give the link's a common class and use that

Comment: Can you change the IDs to be unique or give a class to them - also you have `dl.faz2music.ir` in the code but mysite.com in the link href.
Can we just change ALL hrefs that have `dl.faz2music.ir` and the text of Download?

Comment: So how can I change multiple specified links by clicking on the button

Comment: Give examples. Please update the question to have more than one set of things. Do you have a button for each or one button should change all and I ask again, can you give them a class instead of ID

Comment: OK.. I changed it, see the codes again

Comment: @Faz2Music.ir as i said, give the links a common class and use that, then you can change multiple links at once

Comment: Ok my friend... I have fully updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using each and a class:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#change').on('click', function(e) {
    const from = "dl.faz2music.ir";
    const to = "up.faz2music.ir";
    $(".urlchange").each(function() {
      if (this.matches("source")) {
        console.log()
        this.setAttribute("src", this.getAttribute("src").replace(from,to))
      }  
      else this.href = this.href.replace(from,to);
    });
    /*
    notice.showToast({
      text: 'Links converted',
      type: 'success',
      showClose: true
    });
    */
    alert("Links changed");
  });
  $("audio").on("mouseenter", (e) => console.log(e.target.querySelector("source").getAttribute("src")))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="change">Change</button>

<a href="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [320].mp3" class="urlchange">Download</a>
<a href="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [320].mp3" class="urlchange">Download</a>
<a href="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [320].mp3" class="urlchange">Download</a>
<hr/>
<audio controls><source type="audio/mp3" src="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [320].mp3" class="urlchange"></audio><br/>
<audio controls>Audio<source type="audio/mp3" src="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [128].mp3" class="urlchange"></audio>
```

Comment: thank you... i update my question.. Can you check again?
I also added the player option

Comment: I put your codes and they worked on my site

Comment: I changed to fix the source in the audio tag too. Note I changed to class

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign same class to anchor tags as you can not assign same ids to multiple tags

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#change').on('click', function (e) {
            $('.urlchange').prop('href',  (i, val) => {
                return val.replace("dl.faz2music.ir", "up.faz2music.ir");
            });
           // notice.showToast({ text: 'Links converted', type: 'success', showClose: true });
        });
 });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-tG5mcZUtJsZvyKAxYLVXrmjKBVLd6VpVccqz/r4ypFE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="change" class="ltr">Change links</button>
<a href="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [320].mp3" class="urlchange">Download</a>
<a href="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [320].mp3" class="urlchange">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), note that `.attr` has an overload which takes a callback:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

> `.attr( attributeName, function )`
>
> attributeName - Type: `String` 
>  The name of the attribute to set.
>
> function Type: `Function( Integer index, String attr )` returns `String` or `Number` 
>  A function returning the value to set. `this` is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old attribute value as arguments.

So, combining with using a class as suggested in other comments/answers, your code becomes:

```
$(".urlchange").attr("href", (_, href) => href.replace("dl.faz2music.ir", "up.faz2music.ir"));
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#change').on('click', function(e) {

    $(".urlchange").attr("href", (_, href) =>
      href.replace("dl.faz2music.ir", "up.faz2music.ir"));

    console.log("urls updated");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [320].mp3" class="urlchange">Download</a>
<a href="https://dl.faz2music.ir/download/3712434/Ahmad Solo - Shazdeh Pesar [128].mp3" class="urlchange">Download</a>

<button id="change" class="ltr">change links</button>
```